# Find start node of a graph in C++ map

Tags: c++, graph, dictionary

Lets suppose I have some tickets to go from some places to some other places. But These are not in order. So  lets suppose I have tickets like:
input: [('E', 'F'), ('D', 'E'), ('C', 'D'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C')]
Now I want to find the full path in which i can use these tickets to travel the full journey
output:  [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E'), ('E', 'F')]

To implement it in C++, I am using c++ stl map. My sample code in C++ looks like:

```
void find_path(std::map<char, char> mymap, char start_node)  
{  
    cout << start_node;
    char val = start_node; 

    while (mymap.count(val) > 0)
    {
        val = mymap.find(val)->second;
        cout << val;
    }
}

int main()  
{
        std::map<char,char> mymap;  
        mymap['E'] = 'F';  
        mymap['D'] = 'E';  
        mymap['C'] = 'D';  
        mymap['A'] = 'B';  
        mymap['B'] = 'C';

        char start_node = find_node(mymap);
        std::cout<<"start node is " << start_node << "\n";

        find_path(mymap, start_node);      
}
```

Now I am a bit stuck in how to find the start node (how to write find_node() method).
Any option that i can think of now, requires extra space:
1. I can easily find the end node. And then create a new map by reversing all the edges. And that way find the path from end node to start node.
2. Find those nodes whose count is 1 (only 2, start and end node). Now since we can easily find the end node. That way we will get to know start node.

Both suggested methods require extra space. Can anyone suggest me an easy way to find the start node.

Comment: start for what path? the longest? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Find the node with no incoming connections?

Comment: by what criteria would you look for the "start"?

Comment: How is this a question about c++ or stl? It sounds like a question about graph algorithms

Comment: sorry for the unclear question. I have explained my problem and what all i tried in detail. Kindly check once and suggest me some pointers

Answer (score 2):

You know how long the path from begin to the end is (5 in your case). For each ticket you have, you can determine the length from its start to the full path end. E.g. for ticket D,E the remaining length is just 2. So just check all tickets until you find A,B which has remaining length 5 equal to the total length. No extra space needed but O(N*N) runtime.
[edit]
Actually, O(N*N*log(N)) since map lookup is O(log N)

Comment: Thanks MSalters. Yes I also thought about this approach. But as you said it will make it O(N*N) runtime. But I am looking for O(N) time and O(1) space, if it is possible

Comment: Just looking up N map elements is already O(N log N) so I don't expect your method can achieve O(N).